# Leaflet Toggle groupLayer of markers with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, click, toggle

I'd like to create a **click function** to *show* and *hide* my markers (clicking in a img logo next to my map).

I have an img logo:

```
<a title="Curieux" id="folieLogo"><img class="logo deuz" src="Icons/icons8-trampoline-96.png"></a>
```

I have my layer group in a var "nordLayer":

```
     var nordLayer = L.layerGroup([markerA,markerB, markerC])
```

The function to show markers :

```
     $("#folieLogo").click(function() {var nordLayer = L.layerGroup([markerA,markerB, markerC]).addTo(mymap).toggle("slow");
 });
```

When i click on my logo it shows my markers but does not hide them on second click.
Please help. Thanks a lot for taking time.

[My map with logos around it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jifu6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and remove the layerGroup each time the user clicks the image.

```
var nordLayer = L.layerGroup([markerA,markerB,markerC]).addTo(mymap);

$("#folieLogo").click( function () {
  //check if the nordLayer is defined
  //if defined, remove the layer from the map
  if (nordlayer) {
    nordlayer.removeLayer();
  //if the nordlayer is not defined
  //this will added to the map
  } else {
    nordLayer = L.layerGroup([markerA,markerB,markerC]).addTo(mymap);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it with the help of a friend, big up to you EDEN!

Still have my layerGroup of markers called "nordLayer"

```
var nordLayer = L.layerGroup([markerA,markerB, markerC])
```

So we have to set a new variable with =0 for status we'll call it "clickFolie":

```
var clickFolie = 0;
```

and then create a function incliding the click change status:

```
     document.getElementById("folieLogo").onclick = function() { 
  if(clickFolie%2===0){
   nordLayer.addTo(mymap);
  }
 else{
   nordLayer.remove();
  } 
  clickFolie+=1;
 }
```

Working well for me now. Thanks to my buddy. Hope it'll help sbdy.